# how to set the entry-point of a pytest plugin in a conda-forge recipe?

Tags: recipe, conda-forge

I'm packaging an existing pytest-plugin as a conda-forge recipe. It's the first time I face entr-points and I don't know what to do with the pytest one.

The section in the `pyproject.toml` file is as follow:

```ini
[project.entry-points."pytest11"]
copie = "pytest_copie.plugin"
```

How should it be translated in the `meta.yaml` file of a conda-forge recipe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to add from your side, it will work naturally.
Have a look to pytest-gee recipe: https://github.com/conda-forge/pytest-gee-feedstock/blob/main/recipe/meta.yaml